# How to add a multiple choice question requiring a single selection?

Tags: google-forms

I am creating a Google Form for company's internal survey.

Currently there are seven question types:

- Text
- Paragraph text
- Multiple choice
- Checkboxes
- Choose from a list
- Scale
- Grid

I am looking to add a question with Yes/No options, like this one "Do you own an IBM PC?" which will have only one answer, either Yes or No.

One option is to use "Choose from list" which will render a dropdown list but tat seems awkward to me. I've checked "Make this question required" and by default 'Yes' will be displayed but there is no guarantee attendees will read all available options.

Is there any workaround to display two radio buttons, instead of a dropdown, to ask these kinds of questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get Radio Buttons on a Google Docs Form, you need set the Question Type to `Multiple Choice`

[image: Google Docs Forms - Radio Buttons]

Comment: duh! I didn't tried that one :)